# React-Three-Fiber update canvas dimension dynamically on container size change

Tags: react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I building an application where my react-three-canvas is inside a div and css animations are taking place on this div. The issue is the canvas dimension are only taking place after the transition or animation has completed.

I would like it to behave exactly like onWindowResize works. Any insight on how to achieve this?

[image]

In this GIF you can see a delay where the canvas paint area is not updating until css completes a transition.

```
<div id={ s.UserView }>
            
  

     <Canvas shadows={ false } orthographic camera={{ position: [ 0, 0, 200 ] }} ref={ SceneRef } dpr={ DPR } gl={{ outputColorSpace: THREE.SRGBColorSpace, toneMapping: THREE.NoToneMapping }}>
                <MapCam targetRef={ containerRef } HUDRef={ HUDRef }  sceneFrame={ data.frame } sceneGrids={ data.grids }/>
                <SceneRoot setCursor={ setCursor } mapFilters={ mapFilters } cells={ data.grids } cellsIndex={ cellsIndex }/>
     </Canvas>

            <HUD passRef={ HUDRef }/>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved my issue. I found resize params have an option for debouncing that is not 0 by default. Setting this to 0 creates smooth resizing of the canvas when built-in resizeObserver detects changes to parent div.

```
<Canvas shadows={ false } resize={{ debounce: 0 }} ... />
```